# Swift how to set Editor crop size for editor in UIImagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

For my iOS app I need a Fotoeditor. Therefore I set:

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
```

Now I would like to change the size of the editable area.

Here is the editable area, but I need the size of the usable image different:

[image]

How can I change the size of this area to use a different size for the usable image area?

Here is my code for my PickerController

```
@IBOutlet weak var preview: UIImageView!

let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func selectImage(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        preview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        preview.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You can't change it.

Comment: You can provide your own cameraOverlayView which can show a viewfinder of any size. but it will still take the picture in the same way. you have to manually crop it based on the provided cropRect and your custom overlayView logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to save the edited image from the library or the camera and I didn't find anything on the web so I try this code and it works! Swift 4.2

```
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
            imageProfile.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageProfile.image = pickedImage
}
```

this lines of code have to be inside the function

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]){}
```

Comment: what is `imageProfile`?

Comment: I believe that's just the name of Christian's UIImageView variable where he's setting the image to.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible via UIImagePickerController, you can use this library to implement this feature ([GKImagePicker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker)).

Answer (score 0):

use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` this code
for example :-

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage{
        preview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        preview.image = pickedImage
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check Image height and width :-

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {return}
        imageView.image = image
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print(image.size.height)
        print(image.size.width)
        print(image.size)
    }
```